# Street Fighter 3 not working on startup (retropie)

Tags: retropie, emulation, games

I have a retropie and I want to play street fighter 3 on it. So I downloaded the zip file (sfiii3.zip) into the /roms/fba/ directory and when I try to run the game the screen goes black and then goes back to the menu.

How do I fix this, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try unzipping the file then place it into the rom folder. If that doesn't work try and find another copy of street fighter rom. Hope that helps